# Is it possible to get the UUID of a chromecast receiver from the receiver app itself?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I'm developing a chromecast app, and would like the receiver to be able to identify itself with a server. I notice it's possible to get the UUID of the chromecast in the sender app - it's a part of the [`Receiver`](https://developers.google.com/cast/reference/chrome/jsdoc/cast.Receiver) object.

Whilst I appreciate I could send this data *back* to the Receiver from the Sender, I was wondering if there's any way to get this programmatically on the Receiver side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ed, in the current SDK, you do not have access to that information on the receiver side directly. If you share with us the use case that you have in mind, we may be able to suggest an alternate approach that would work for you.

Comment: That's okay, I have several alternatives, I just wanted to know if this approach was Viable